# How to delete TeamCity tags across all builds?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

The only way I can find to delete a TeamCity tag is to remove all references to the tag from all builds. This is a manual and laborious process. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible in TeamCity UI. As workaround you can use REST API. To find all builds use the request:

```
http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=tags:<tag_name>
```

Then for each build get the list of tags:

```
http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:<buildId>/tags
```

Delete needed tag in returned XML and use [PUT request](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildTags) to replace tags.

There is no related ticket in [TeamCity tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW), so you can fill one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database you can also hard delete it from there.